# How to open a jQuery dialog box only when first visited/refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to set a specific webpage to auto open a jQuery dialog box only when first visited/refreshed and not open every time other pages lead to the page?

```
/*HTML*/
<div id="dialog" title = "Welcome" class="white">
    <p>Please Enter Your Name</p>
    <label for="FirstName">Name: </label>
    <input type = "text" id="input"/>        
</div>

/*jQuery*/
$(function () {   
$("#dialog").dialog({
modal: true,
dialogClass: 'defaultDialogClass',
buttons:{
    Ok: function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");               
                  }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please write what have you tried.

Comment: use `localStorage` for this.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute simplest way:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('visitedOnce')) {
  // Your code for showing the modal/whatever
  localStorage.setItem('visitedOnce', '1');
}
```

You're setting a flag on the user's machine that says they have been there, then checking when the page loads if that flag has been set.

Check [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) here

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Andrew answered your question. Just adding this since you also want to run the dialog when the page is reloaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//run the method
checkWhatsGoingOn();
});


var checkWhatsGoingOn = function(){
//if page is reloaded or localstorage value's pair is not set 
if((location.reload()) || (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) ){
    //set it to true
localStorage.setItem('visited', 'true');
//run the dialog
myDialog();

}
}

var myDialog = function(){
$("#dialog").dialog({
modal: true,
dialogClass: 'defaultDialogClass',
buttons:{
    Ok: function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");               
                  }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps as well.